# JQuery - Minha queue não funciona mais de uma vez nessa animação. O que pode ser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação

Criei uma função a qual quando o mouse passasse por cima da DIV, ela faria uma animação inserindo e removendo classes. Mas o que eu não entendo é que a animação que está dentro da queue,  só funciona a primeira vez.
Quando passo o mouse novamente, ela não funciona. Tentei até o usar o console.log() pra ver o que era, e realmente, depois da segunda vez, ele nem entrava na Queue.

```
divTarget2.hover(function(){

       console.log(stats);
       $(this).find('img').addClass('anima-doenca-hover').delay(1000).
           queue(function(){
               console.log('entrou na queue');

               $(this).parent().addClass('anima-caixa-hover');

               console.log(stats);   
            });
            soundEffect.play();

}).mouseleave(function(){

        $(this).find('img').removeClass('anima-doenca-hover');

        $(this).removeClass('anima-caixa-hover');

        soundEffect.pause();
        soundEffect.currentTime = 0;
        console.log(stats);

        });
```

Comment: Quando você tira o mouse, ele retorna ao estado original ?

Comment: Sim, quando eu tiro o mouse ele remove a class e volta o original certinho. O problema é quando eu vou tentar passar o mouse novamente, ele só executa uma das animações, mas a que está dentro da Queue não executa mais.Mas o que eu não entendo, é que de primeira vez que eu passo o mouse ela funciona certinho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução funcional pra isso, seria você adicionar a própria div, eventos do mouse para disparar sua função.

```html
   <!-- DIV a ser animada -->

  <div id="idMinhaDiv" onmouseover="chamaEfeitos()" onmouseout="cancelaEfeitos()">
      <!-- conteúdo da DIV -->
  </div>
```

Outra forma seria você transformar seu código em duas partes diferentes apenas com `mouseover` e `mouseout`

```js
var time; // Variável para armazenar o temporizador (Necessário apenas para interrompe-lo)

$("#idMinhaDiv").on("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("anima-caixa-hover");
    $(this).toggleClass("qualquer-classe");
    this.time = setTimeout(() => {executaComDelay();},2000); // Executa com delay
    // E suas outras instruções e funções.
});

$("#idMinhaDiv").on("mouseout",function(){
    clearTimeout(this.time); // Para ele executar mesmo com o mouse já saído de cima, remova essa linha 
    $(this).removeClass("anima-caixa-hover");
    $(this).removeClass("qualquer-classe");
    // E suas outras instruções e funções.
});

function executaComDelay(){
  // função executada com delay
}
```

Veja o exemplo -> [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvpjazu/) <-

Comment: Tentei fazer mas ta com o mesmo problema. Porque a parte de chamada do evento ta funcionando certinho, o que está dando errado é na minha primeira função de Hover. Que eu quero que ele execute uma instrução JQuery e logo em seguida outra com Delay, por isso utilizei o Delay e a Queue. Mas o problema, é que quando é passado o mouse pela primeira vez funcionam as duas instruções certinho. Mas, quando o mouse é tirado e é passado pela segunda vez, ele simplesmente executa a primeira instrução, mas a segunda que está dentro da Queue após Delay não.

Comment: Eu mudei o exemplo, dá uma olhada novamente. Pelo que eu entendi, ele não está passando no queue na segunda vez. Tenta mudar a abordagem deste delay. Olha o exemplo que eu fiz.

Comment: Seu console não indica nenhum erro?

Comment: nenhum, creio que seja erro semântico. Mas já resolvi já, troquei o delay do jquery pelo setTimeout do Javascript, e funcionou muito bem.

Comment: Show! Boa sorte em seus projetos! ;)

Comment: vlw cara, te desejo o mesmo!